# How can MQL5 WebRequest() call to non-standard ports?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

There is said in the MQL5 **`WebRequest()`** documentation "Server port is automatically selected on the basis of the specified protocol - 80 for "http://" and 443 for "https://"."

Do you know some alternative to call non standard ports?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### No.

There is no such way in the native MQL5 **`WebRequest()`** call.

### But:

In case one is interested in allowing a generic web-service integration with a MQL4/5 DSL domain, one ought [review **`ZeroMQ`** or **`nanomsg`** signalling / messaging frameworks, that **allow MQL4/5**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5BMQL4%5D%20ZeroMQ) side to communicate ( and do much more interesting stuff ) with other, distributed, system nodes without any such restriction.

Answer (score 0):

From build 1995, you can now [use Socket() on any port](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/303721) (see point 13) without using any DLL or third-party tool.